# Python - Condition and Loops

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
spam = input()


if spam == 1:
 print("Hello Word")
if spam == 2:
 print("Howdy")
else:
 print("Greetings")
    

#Task if spam == 1 then print Hello World if spam == 2 print Howdy and if
#anything else print greeetings
```

However my code is printing greetings on any input.

Comment: `input` will always return a string. Try comparing `spam == '1'` and `spam == '2'`.

Comment: Just change the second if statement to elif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using elif (else if)

```
spam = input()


if spam == '1':
 print("Hello Word")
elif spam == '2':
 print("Howdy")
else:
 print("Greetings")
```

Comment: You should also make it clear that `spam` is a string and needs to be compared to one.

Answer (score 1):

Since `input()` accepts string, you could cast the variable into an int to compare:

```
spam = input()

if int(spam) == 1:
    print("Hello World")
elif int(spam) == 2:
    print("Howdy")
else:
    print("Greetings")
```

Comment: `else if` is not valid syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of the wrong language

Comment: Yes I guessed you'd probably been writing a lot of C (or similar) recently :)

Comment: c# and c++ mostly

Answer (score 0):

Your input is formatted as a string, you have to convert it to an int with `int()`.

bests

Answer (score 0):

Change the second if to elif. The then sequence should operate as expected.

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if it's equal to a number not a string; input returns a string not a number.

you can fix this in two ways:

1. change the statement to be `spam == "1"`
2. change `spam = int(input())`

Answer (score 0):

The input you are asking the user is of type integer, but the default input type is string
this can be checked by

```
type(spam)
```

what you want to do is

```
spam = int(input())
if spam == 1:
    print("Hello Word")
elif spam == 2:
    print("Howdy")
else:
    print("Greetings")
```